# Slack API Check Admin Status

Tags: oauth, slack-api, slack

Using slack oauth [api](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) i setup an app for user to login, the app is accessable to both admin & user, the problem is that even calling [auth.access](https://slack.com/api/oauth.access), i am able to get token details, but there i cannot find any way to find if the logined user is admin or not, response is same for both admin & normal user.
response from auth.access

```
{
   "ok": true, 
   "user_id": "UNxxxxxxx', 
   "access_token": "xoxp-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-......xx", 
   "bot": {
       "bot_access_token": "xoxb-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
       "bot_user_id": "Uxxxxxxxx"
   }, 
   "team_id": "Txxxxxxxxx", 
   "scope": "identify,bot,channels:read,users:read...", 
   "team_name": "Team Name"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could compare the user's ID with their entry in the [`users.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) API method. Each user has elements for `is_owner` and `is_admin`.

Here's a shortened version of the example response from the page:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "U023BECGF",
            "team_id": "T021F9ZE2",
            "name": "bobby",
            ...
            "is_admin": true,
            "is_owner": true,
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ooh i found the correct api, there is https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info method :), Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dont know answering my own question is good or not, when i checked slack oauth documentation suggested by **Heiko Koelle**, found the answer [users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info)
will respond back `"is_admin"` and `"is_owner"` boolean values, was in hurry :)